# jquery Datatables row highlighting not working

Tags: jquery

I have this table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<div class="card-body">

    <table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">        
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="big-col">Id</th>
                <th class="big-col">Name</th>
                <th class="big-col">Project</th>
```

and the this code to highligh the row upon selection. But it didn't work.

```
 $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {


                var data = table.api()
                            .row($(this).closest('tr'))
                            .data();


                $('#userid').val(data.Id);
                $("#dataTable tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');
```

**My Problem:**

I'm pretty sure that clicking on the body is working since I can get the id, but the row highlighting is not working.

I have also this on my css:

```
tr.row_selected td{

background-color:rgba(116, 206, 80, 1) !important;

}
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr')` you dont need closest since you click the tr itself

Comment: @guradio, upon removing that code, i'm not enable to retrieve the data when selecting the row.

Comment: When i delete all lines about getting data, this row selected is working flawless. Problem should be here somewhere. What is your datatables version?

Comment: Also it can be better if you explain what is `userid` element and what you want to do with this code exactly.

Comment: @ReadyFreddy, I'm using 1.10.16

Comment: @ReadyFreddy, upon clicking the row, i'm storing the userid to a hidden textbox. This is because i want to have a normal post method instead of using ajax post.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [this page about datatables api usage](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) you can see it's different to call script as `dataTable` and `DataTable`. In this case, your problem is about that. Check this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

var tableApi = $('#dataTable').dataTable();

    $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
            var data = tableApi.api().row($(this)).data();
            console.log(data);
            $('#userid').val(data[0]);
            $("#dataTable tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    });
});
```

```css
tr.row_selected td{

background-color:rgba(116, 206, 80, 1) !important;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">        
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="big-col">Id</th>
            <th class="big-col">Name</th>
            <th class="big-col">Project</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>TestName</td>
          <td>TestProj</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>TestName</td>
          <td>TestProj</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>TestName</td>
          <td>TestProj</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but i've tried to use your code and still nothing happens, getting row data items and row highlight selection.

Comment: since the snippet is working, there can be a problem about calling script file, calling css file or getting data from table. Can you please control your browser dev-console and check if there is any error for scripts? In case of you don't know how to do it: Example on chome right click on page, click "Inspect", select "Console" from top bar and see if there is any errors.

Comment: Also can you show us where did you add script and css to code.